# Rails Checkbox not working - no error when submitting form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, associations

I have a problem with a checkbox in Rails:

I have two models, User and authorized_users, with the following association:

```
class AuthorizedUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as => :useraccount
```

and:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :useraccount, :polymorphic => true, :dependant => :destroy
```

In the "edit" view of the User I want a checkbox for cheking if the Authorized_user should recieve an email (true) or not (false):

```
<%= check_box(:authorized_user, :sendEmail, options = {:checked => true}, checked_value =  true, unchecked_value = false) %>
```

The same exact code is working perfect in the "new" view of the Authorized_user, when creating a new user, but when I edit them, with the "edit" view of user, no error is displayed submiting the form, but the boolean cell in the database is not being affected.

What do I need to modify so that when I submit the form, the changes are saved?

Thank you very much in advance.

Pd: For more information I can say that other data is being modified with no problem in this "edit" view from user, for exmaple:

```
<%= f.text_field :phone %>
```

Error log after changing:

```
<% f.check_box :sendEmail %>
```

suggested by @marek-lipka

```
NoMethodError in Users#edit

Showing app/views/users/edit.html.erb where line #64 raised:

undefined method `sendEmail' for #<User:0xb5dbd96c>  

Extracted source (around line #64):  

63:   <p>¿Desea recibir e-mails?/p>  
64:   <p><%= f.check_box :sendEmail %></p>  
65: <%end%>  
66: <br />
```

After a long discussion with @marek-lipka we got the clue:

We must use :useraccount as the linker action and not :authorized_user:

```
<%= check_box(:useraccount, :sendEmail, options = {:checked => true}, checked_value =  true, unchecked_value = false) %>
```

Comment: You should adopt Ruby/Rails naming conventions.

Comment: What is `check_box`? Did you mean to use `check_box_tag` or `f.check_box`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this problem because you don't use actual object when rendering this check box. It should probably be:

```
<%= f.check_box :send_email %>
```

Note that I used `send_email` name in Rails convention, which you should adopt.

Comment: Hi @marek-lipka,

Thanks for your help.


I'm quite new to rails and i did "inherit" a project where I need to start making some changes...

When I put:

    <%= f.check_box :send_email %>

I have teh following error:

    undefined method 'sendEmail'

I suppose i must tell checkbox that sendEmail belongs to AuthorizedUser action somehow.

Trying to figuring out how...

I will take good note about the naming conventions.

Comment: @anexo not exactly. The question here is if this `sendMail` is a field in `authorized_users` table because these fields are bound to `ActiveRecord` object, not controller actions.

Comment: Yes it is a Field inside authorized_users table with Type: tinyint(1)

Comment: @anexo so it should work. If it doesn't, please post full error message with backtrace.

Comment: Here is the error log, hope it helps, thanks a lot for the effort:

NoMethodError in Users#edit

Showing app/views/users/edit.html.erb where line #64 raised:
 
undefined method `sendEmail' for #<User:0xb5dbd96c>  

Extracted source (around line #64):  

63:   <p>¿Desea qué este usuario autorizado reciba e-mails de notificaciónes?</p>  
64:   <p><%= f.check_box :sendEmail %></p>  
65: <%end%>  
66: <br />

Comment: @anexo could you paste it in question? It would be much more readable.

Comment: @anexo I know why you have this error. It's because you actually display form for `User`, not for `AuthorizedUser` object.

Comment: I just put the code in the question. Yes the form is being displayed for User, that why I supposed I must connect the two models somehow, if I'm not to lost (surely I am...)

Comment: @anexo You can then either use [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) or [form objects](http://matthewrobertson.org/blog/2012/09/20/decoupling-rails-forms-from-the-database/).

Comment: I got the answer, stupid by my side i was using :authorized_user and not :useraccount in the checkbox as the "linker" action. I will edit the question so I the answer is shown for people havins similar problems. Thank you very much for your help and making me think! I will have a look at accepts_nested_attributes_for or form objects as you advice me!